# instanceOf operator in java

Tags: java, instanceof

Why is this line of code in Java not printing the message?

```
System.out.println("a instanceof String:"+a instanceof String);
```

Why is it just printing true and not the String before it???

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what `a` is?

Comment: @RC.: As it happens, it doesn't matter. But yes, a [mcve] would be better.

Comment: @JonSkeet I saw your answer, so yes it doesn't matter in that case ;)

Answer (score 8):

Ah, the joys of operator precedence. That line is effectively:

```
System.out.println(("a instanceof String:" + a) instanceof String);
```

... so you're doing string concatenation, and then checking whether the result is a string. So it will *always* print `true`, regardless of the value of `a`.

You just need parentheses

```
System.out.println("a instanceof String:" + (a instanceof String));
```

See the [Java tutorial page on operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) for a precedence list.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will be executed as follows:

**`System.out.println(("a instanceof String:"+a) instanceof String);`**

So, the whole string i.e., `("a instanceof String:"+a)` has been considered for the `instanceof` check.

In order to print, `"a instanceof String:true"`, you need to use parenthesis at the right place:

```
System.out.println("a instanceof String:" + (a instanceof String));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use brackets.

```
System.out.println(("a instanceof String:"+a) instanceof String);
```